# Excel sheet formula

Tags: excel

I have excel file having sheets month wise. more than 1000 lines items with different prices in each month. i want to make one sheet of each items segregating prices by months.
for Example,
if (column A1) item is matching to (sheet1 Column A) than put the (Sheet1 column C Value) in (column C).

**Item #       Jan Price          Feb Price       Mar Price**

Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
Item 5
Item 6

please help.

Comment: Have a look at hte [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65)

Comment: [vlookup](https://youtu.be/DBEyr-9ZSN4)

Comment: How do you use VLOOKUP to find the matching item and see if the date is within the given month? I'm thinking a pivot table or MATCH with conditions.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean, didn't read it properly.

Comment: can you give me the formula to use???

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `1` is in B2 the other sheets are called `Sheet2`, `Sheet3` etc then in C2 and copied down to suit and all the formulae copied across (presumably eleven column) to suit:

```
=VLOOKUP($B2,INDIRECT("Sheet"&COLUMN()-2&"!A:C"),3,0)
```